# "Waiting for emulator..." in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-emulator, visual-studio-2015

I trying to deploy Native activity application(Android, C++) on the Visual Studio 2015 embedded emulator, OS: Windows 10. But have a problem:

After the start of building and deploying I get stuck on this window:

[image]

And output says that:

> ------Deploy started: Project: Android1.Packaging, Configuration: Debug x86
>
> Starting emulator...

So I can see only this infinite window.

How can I fix it and start emulator?

**UPD:**

If I launch emulator from the Visual Studio Emulator for Android manager, then I get this:
[image]
 And log says:

> 3> 20.01.2016 21:03:02 : [Critical] An error occured while creating
>   'VS Emulator 7" KitKat (4.4) XHDPI Tablet' device.
>
> 3> 20.01.2016 21:03:02 : [Critical] XDE Path: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10240.0\xde.exe
>
> 3> 20.01.2016 21:03:02 : [Critical] XDE Arguments: /sku Android
>   /displayName "VS Emulator 7\" KitKat (4.4) XHDPI Tablet" /memSize 1024
>   /diagonalSize 7 /video "1200x1920" /vhd
>   "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\vhd\7_KitKat_(4.4)_XHDPI_Tablet\image.vhd"
>   /name "VS Emulator 7-inch KitKat (4.4) XHDPI Tablet.user" /noStart
>   /silent
>
> 3> 20.01.2016 21:03:02 : [Critical] XDE Exit Code: InvalidArguments
>   (3)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32560853/app-not-run-in-visual-studio-emulator-for-android-in-visual-studio-2015/32564067#32564067

Comment: What happens when you go to Tools > Visual Studio Emulator for Android and start a profile from the emulator manager?

Comment: @JohnKemnetz I have tested it, please check the updated question.

Comment: @user2656632 - can you go to command prompt, cd to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10240.0\ and type xde.exe /sku Android /displayName "VS Emulator 7\" KitKat (4.4) XHDPI Tablet" /memSize 1024 /diagonalSize 7 /video "1200x1920" /vhd "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\vhd\7_KitKat_(4.4)_XHDPI_Tablet\image.vhd" /name "VS Emulator 7-inch KitKat (4.4) XHDPI Tablet.user"

That will run it without /silent /nostart and will show a more verbose error.

Comment: @JohnKemnetz I get [window like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/egDzg.png) but about Visual Studio emulator for Android instead of Windows Phone emulator(I did not attached the image because I have the Russian version of Windows).