# VS Android emulator issue. "Preparing virtual machine..."

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-emulator, visual-studio-2015

I still trying to deploy Native activity application(Android, C++) on the Visual Studio 2015 embedded emulator, OS: Windows 10. But I get a new problems without solving previous(I still have [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34891511/waiting-for-emulator-in-visual-studio-2015)):

If I launch emulator from the Visual Studio Emulator for Android manager, then I stuck on this: [image]
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31698124/2656632) answer did not help me.
How I can fix these issues and start the emulator?

Comment: Do you have the latest MS Android Emulator installed?  There's a new(er) one lately.

Comment: I know this sounds weird, but is your WiFi or Ethernet connections showing as "bridged" in your Network Connections?  I recall fighting something about that too.

Comment: @SteveKennedy sorry for the late reply, I have the Network Connection parameters exactly like on [this screen](http://www.tenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/20981d1433698173-network-location-set-private-public-windows-10-a-network_location_ethernet_settings-1.png).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I just solve it by **DESACTIVE** the **Wifi network card**.

Then start emulator from VS, it creates the virtual machine which can be seen in panel "Manage Hyper-V".

Answer (score 0):

What I did to fix this exact problem was:

1. Delete all Virtual Switchs on Hyper-V Manager.
2. Uninstall **all** my Network devices on Devices Manager.
3. Reboot.