# Android emulator in visual studio does not load my app

Tags: android, visual-studio-2012, xamarin, android-sdk-tools

I have integrated and installed android jdk and xamarin for visual studio. As a beginner I have created my first sample app with 2 to 3 controls to check the setup. I am trying to run the application and was expecting android emulator 'Android 7.1 -API 25) to load my app and render it. But though the emulator is getting instantiated, it is not loading the app and the vs keeps on showing the in progress bar at the bottom build status bar. I have also enabled emulated performance to hardware as my system supports it. My system has enough ram, but it still does not load the app.

[image]

Regards
Surojit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App not run in visual studio emulator for android in visual studio 2015](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32560853/app-not-run-in-visual-studio-emulator-for-android-in-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: visual studio or google emulator?
does the emulator start up?
did you unlock the android screen?  real question, had a friend who didn't know he had to do this.

Comment: I also get this on both my computers. I find that it deploys reliably to Genymotion emulators however.

Answer (score 0):

Please check hardware visualization is enabled or not. Go to Bios setup >> configuration >> Intel Virtual Technology and enable it. This configuration is working for Intel processor windows OS.