# Visual Studio Emulator For Android do not run vs 2017 with windows 10 pro

Tags: android, xamarin, android-emulator, visual-studio-2017, emulation

I'm installed Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10 Pro. And then install Hyper-V services , visual studio android emulator. Now all of them running well.

But when debug xamarin solutions in VS2017 "Preparing Virtual Machines" status waiting a lot time but don't run. I Can't see virtual machine into Hyper-V Virtual Machine list.

Please help me please... What can I do ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App not run in visual studio emulator for android in visual studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32560853/app-not-run-in-visual-studio-emulator-for-android-in-visual-studio-2015)

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of hyper-v (or disabling it) and install HAXM from Intel. Run the 86x bit versions of the emulators and everything should work just fine.