# Xamarin app not deploying to VS Simulator for Android

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, deployment, visual-studio-2017

I installed Xamarin tool on VS, the right Android SDK, and the Android Emulator for Android from Microsoft.

When I run the application from Visual Studio, the last step I get to is

```
1>Emulator launched successfully.
```

And the Xamarin Diagnostics give me

```
[I:]:                     Found Xamarin.Android 8.0.2.1
[I:sdk]:                  Runtime path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android
[I:sdk]:                  Framework path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\VisualStudio\15.0_a2cdabb9\Android\AndroidSdkDirectory found:
    Path contains adb in \platform-tools (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk).
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\VisualStudio\15.0_a2cdabb9\Android\AndroidNdkDirectory found:
    Path contains ndk-stack in \. (C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r13b).
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\VisualStudio\15.0_a2cdabb9\Android\JavaSdkDirectory found:
    Path contains jarsigner.exe in \bin (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131).
[I:]:                     Found Android SDK. API levels: 17, 25
[I:]:                     Tracking android devices started
[D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: 
[I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 0 devices
[D:]:                     Tracking avd started
[D:]:                     avd watcher *.ini path: 'C:\Users\Dmitri\.android\avd'
[D:]:                     avd watcher: got device list from avd with 0 devices
```

And that's it. Nothing happens. The emulator is showing the lock screen.

How do I get this process moving? I want to run the app!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App not run in visual studio emulator for android in visual studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32560853/app-not-run-in-visual-studio-emulator-for-android-in-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: Note this `Got new device list from adb with 0 devices`, it means that can't find your emulator. Have you activated Intel Virtual Technology from BIOS?

Comment: @JoeLv I'm using the Microsoft emulator

Comment: check weather Android SDK Api Levels 19,21 are installed in 
Tools -> Android -> Android SDK Manager

Comment: @Divya everything's installed